# ASIHTTPRequest reload/refresh at runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

In my app I want that whenever the web service is updated with new data my app synchronise with it. But currently what is happening is that I have to log out and then again log in to the app to see the updated results. Is there any way to update my app without log out and log in again?

Comment: we need more details about what you are doing, otherwise it is impossible to help you. All the ways, accordingly to your description, I think that the problem is that you are only refreshing the data when the user log in.

Comment: Please provide some more details regarding your problem

Comment: @thanzakic: you understood right..what should is do to refresh in between the app?

Comment: @Wolvorin: what i want is i am using a web service in which new profiles for a user can be added at any point of time, you can think of it as a social n/w web site of which's web service i am using.But when a profile is added and my app is already running i cant see the new added profile in the app which is only fetched upon log out and log in again. But i want that the new data should be updated within my app while it is already running

Comment: For that you have to run the webService for reloading the data from n/w web site. and then reload the table using it's `reloadData` property.

Comment: You need to update the dataSource (ie the array used to load the table) of the tableView first

Comment: yes..how do i update the array?

Comment: Just call the ASIHTTPRequest again as you call it on launch of application or on login time and reload the array again with new data received by the ASIHTTPRequest :)

Comment: Also you can do this with some button click or pull to refresh mechanism or use the NSTimmer for calling it with fixed period of time :)

Comment: Thnx Wolvorin, it did help somewhat..:)

Comment: Welcome @user1845209 love to help and be helped, too :)

Comment: If you wish you can hit service after fixed interval using timer from you app delegate  notificationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(notificationUpdater) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];